# t-sql select one column if record exists, different column if not

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, exists, isnull

I often find myself with a need to select a value from one of two different tables, tableA and tableB.  If a certain record exists in tableA, I grab the value from tableA. If the record does not exist, I instead need a value from tableB.

I am working with an ERP application that will create an event based record in a sales order ship-to address table if the user changes the default ship-to address when entering a sales order.  If the user does not change the ship-to address, the system assumes the product is being shipped to the address on the customer file and does not write anything to the sales order ship-to table. I need the ship-to address for every sales order shipment, but I am not safe in grabbing it directly from either tableA or tableB.

What I've done in the past is something like this:

```
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN isnull(tableA.SalesOrderNumber, 'StackOverflow') = 'StackOverflow'
            THEN tableB.address1
        ELSE tableA.address1
        END AS address1
```

Which works. But then you end up repeating this same thing over and over again for every field with similar logic, which sucks, but it is not unworkable if the value you are checking for (`SalesOrderNumber`) is character based data and/or a primary key. If the value I am checking for is not a primary key or if it is numeric type data then this approach becomes much more fragile.

There's got to be a better way, right?

I have tried a few different approaches with the `EXISTS` operator and gotten nowhere.

Comment: why don't you use function if you need this type of thing frequently

Comment: the concept is repetitive, the mechanics are not. also, i'm doing this for reporting purposes so i have to be able to incorporate it into a view.  calling 9 different scalar functions for 9 different fields for every row in the resulting view will be slow as all hell

Comment: If you can change the database structure, I would suggest a different approach: Instead of creating this big messy views, I would suggest adding these 9 columns to the orders table, and when the customer submits the order form, populate this columns with values that comes either from the customer's saved data or from the form. You will still have to do the case...when for 9 fields, but only in one place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your task you can left join your `tableA` to check for existence of particular record - if record doesn't exist you will have `NULL` for joined values, otherwise you'll have some value. Then in case `NULL` value you can replace it with a value from `tableB`. Something like this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(tA.address1, tB.address1, N'N/A') AS address1
    FROM tableWithSalesOrderNumbers AS tWSON
             LEFT JOIN tableA AS tA
                 ON tA.SalesOrderNumber = tWSON.SalesOrderNumber
             LEFT JOIN tableB AS tB
                 ON tB.SalesOrderNumber = tWSON.SalesOrderNumber
```

Comment: That's bloody brilliant, not to mention much more elegant.  I had never used coalesce() before but I knew I was making it way more difficult than it needed to be. Thank you